# How to make the punctuations of chinese references in biblatex full-width?

Tags: biblatex

I was writing a [thesis template for CCNU, China](https://github.com/xkwxdyy/CCNUthesis). And one of the requirements of the school is that "All the punctuations in the chinese references must be full-width, including `.`, i.e. `．`".
[image]

And the details are in [here](https://github.com/xkwxdyy/CCNUthesis/issues/1).

Here is a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{ctexart}
\usepackage[backend = biber, style = gb7714-2015]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @article{李晓东CCNUtype,
    author          = {李晓东 and 张庆红 and 叶瑾琳},
    title           = {气候学研究的若干理论问题},
    journaltitle    = {北京大学学报：自然科学版},
    year            = {1999},
    volume          = {35},
    number          = {1},
    pages           = {101-106}
  }
  @article{Ahnrawtype,
    author          = {Steven Ahn and Steven Ahn  and Steven Ahn and Steven D. Tanksley},
    title           = {Comparative linkage maps of the rice and maize genomes},
    journaltitle    = {Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences of the United States of America},
    year            = {1993},
    volume          = {90},
    pages           = {7980-7984}
  }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource[]{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
  text\cite{李晓东CCNUtype}

  text\cite{Ahnrawtype}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

while the ideal result is
[image]

I wonder how to make it?

Comment: There are Unicode characters FULLWIDTH FULL STOP (U+FF0E) and FULLWIDTH COLON (U+FF1A) …

Comment: @Ingmar The problem is that I didn't know how to do it, cuz I know few about biblatex. The grammar is brand new to me.